# django-allauth: Module "accounts.forms" does not define a "SignupForm" class

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am getting the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "accounts.forms"
>   does not define a "SignupForm" class

**settings.py**

```
(...)

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'accounts.forms.SignupForm'

(...)
```

**accounts/forms.py**

```
from allauth.account.forms import BaseSignupForm

class SignupForm(BaseSignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sociallogin = kwargs.pop('sociallogin')
        user = self.sociallogin.account.user
        first_name = forms.CharField(label=_('First name'),
                                     max_length=30,
                                     min_length=2,
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                         'placeholder':_('First name')}))
        last_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Last name'),
                                     max_length=30,
                                     min_length=2,
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                         'placeholder':_('Last name')}))
        second_last_name = forms.CharField(label=_('Second last name'),
                                     max_length=30,
                                     empty='',
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                         'placeholder':_('Second last name')}))
        # TODO: Should become more generic, not listing
        # a few fixed properties.
        initial = {'email': user_email(user) or '',
                   'username': user_username(user) or '',
                   'first_name': user_field(user, 'first_name') or '',
                   'last_name': user_field(user, 'last_name') or ''}
        kwargs.update({
            'initial': initial,
            'email_required': kwargs.get('email_required',
                                         app_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)})
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.save_user(request, self.sociallogin, form=self)
        # TODO: Add request?
        super(SignupForm, self).save(user)
        return user

    def raise_duplicate_email_error(self):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            _("An account already exists with this e-mail address."
              " Please sign in to that account first, then connect"
              " your %s account.")
            % self.sociallogin.account.get_provider().name)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just inherit from `forms.Form` and add the signup function.

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    def signup(self, request, user):
        pass

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'app.forms.CustomSignupForm'
```

Comment: Yes, this is my current setup.

Answer (score 21):

Sir you are victim of Circular Import. allauth tries to import your custom signup form class from `accounts.forms` but in the same file you are importing from allauth `from allauth.account.forms import BaseSignupForm`. You don't need to extend your `SignupForm` from `BaseSignupForm`. Just create a simple form and allauth will automatically extend it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but it was not happening from the SignupForm class, (I referenced it correctly as @aamir suggested).

Instead, it was because I had LoginForm subclassed in the same file as the SignupForm class. For whatever reason, this was also causing a circular import. It also was only happening when I imported views while writing tests, not sure why.

I [found this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945784/keeping-custom-sign-up-class-and-importing-allauth-forms-in-same-forms-py-file-c), which was to just give SignupForm its own forms.py file to live in and it fixed this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try importing SignupForm instead of BaseSignupForm from django-allauth.

Comment: This is not a correct answer, it results in same error. check @aamir-adnan's answer