# django ImproperlyConfigured when subclassing allauth.account.forms.SignUpForm

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm getting an error when running django with a custom signup form for django-allauth which subclasses allauth's default SignupForm. I have

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'rlp.forms.MySignupForm'
```

in `settings.py`, and the code for my form is as follows:

```
class MySignupForm(SignupForm):
    '''
    Add a "Do you wish to contribute?" option to the default non-social
    accounts signup form, and amend the clean method.
    '''

    wishes_to_contribute = forms.BooleanField(label=_(
        'Would you like to request permission to contribute to the '
        'platform?'
        ), widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

    #NOTE: this __init__ may be unnecessary
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(
            MySignupForm, self
            ).clean()
        if cleaned_data['wishes_to_contribute'] == True:
            send_mail(
                'Contributor request: %s'%cleaned_data['username'],
                'New user %s wishes to become a '
                'contributor'%cleaned_data['username'],
                'from@example.com',
                'to@example.com')
        return cleaned_data
```

For a while I thought I was getting an import error with `from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm`, but if I comment out the line in `settings.py` and try running `from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm` in the django shell, it all works fine, so I guess it's not that.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 192, in _base_signup_form_class
    fc_class = getattr(mod, fc_classname)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MySignupForm'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dan_manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 23, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dan/Dropbox/devel/platforms/rlp/admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rlp.forms import EditorAuthenticationForm
  File "/home/dan/Dropbox/devel/platforms/rlp/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 208, in <module>
    class BaseSignupForm(_base_signup_form_class()):
  File "/home/dan/.virtualenvs/platforms/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py", line 196, in _base_signup_form_class
    fc_classname))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "rlp.forms" does not define a "MySignupForm" class
```

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784848/django-allauth-module-accounts-forms-does-not-define-a-signupform-class. It seems to be a circular import issue : your form inherit from django allauth's `SignupForm`, which tries to import your form, etc.

Comment: You're right, this is a duplicate. Apologies.